# Swift: Creating array of Dates in a swifty way

Tags: swift

I'm working with a calendar where I need to create an array of `Date` according to the user selection. I get a `Date` and I calculate the whole week. I'm currently doing that with a *for* loop, but I believe there are better and swiftier ways to do it. I want to go with `map`, but I quite don't see it:

```
private func selectWeek(for date: Date) {
    var week = [Date]()

    if let startOfWeek = date.startOfWeek {
        for delta in 0 ... 6 {
            if let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: delta, to: startOfWeek) {
                week.append(date)
            }
        }
        calendar.selectDates(week)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track, you can use `map`, you just simply need to call it on the range your loop would iterate through.

```
private func selectWeek(for date: Date) {
    if let startOfWeek = date.startOfWeek {
        let week = (0...6).compactMap{Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0, to: startOfWeek)}
        calendar.selectDates(week)
    }
}
```

Comment: `Array(0...6)` that was my missing piece! :-)

Comment: You don't need an `Array`, you can map the range `0...6`

Comment: @gmoraleda updated my answer, simply using `compactMap` instead of `map` gets rid of the `nil` values.

Comment: @MartinR you're right, updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
if let startOfWeek = date.startOfWeek {
    let week = (0...6).compactMap { Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0, to: startOfWeek) }
    calendar.selectDates(week)
}
```

You can directly use `map` (or here `compactMap` to prevent the non nil test) on ranges.

Comment: You don't actually use the return value of the `compactMap` and `week` is undefined due to this. The `compactMap` is also missing its closing curly brackets.

Comment: Oops! Edited! Thanks...

Comment: Good idea using compactMap to deal with the possible nil results from `date(byAdding:value:to:)`

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is fine. If you wanted to use a map statement you could do it like this:

```
let week: [Date]!
if let startOfWeek = date.startOfWeek {
    week = Array(0...6).map {
         Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0, to: startOfWeek)!
    }
}
if week != nil {
  calendar.selectDates(week)
}
```